# ScriptManager WCF Service IE Problem

Tags: asp.net, wcf, scriptmanager

I have a WCF service which I am using through a ScriptManager control:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="/service/client.svc" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

To call methods within this service, I am using some javascript/jQuery:

```
$().ready(function () {
    RefreshClient();
});

function PlaceBid() {    
    var client = new theClient();    
    client.DoSomething(1, 1000, 2000, 50, 5000, 1000, UpdateResult, null, null);
}

function UpdateResult(data){
    // logic and more jQuery to update controls on page
    // e.g. $('#status').html('<div class="something">' + data.msg + '</div>');
}
```

In my Client.svc service I do some calls to a database and then return results based on the database values.

In Chrome, FF, Opera everything works as it should. However, something has gone wrong in IE8/7 which for some strange reason is causing the scripts not to work.

If I debug the project and step through IE works fine, and as I update the database with changes, these changes are then pulled through and the controls on the page (e.g. a simple ) are updated accordingly. AS SOON as i stop debugging, the IE page stops working.

It is as though IE is caching the client.DoSomething function so always returning the original values every time rather than the new values.

Any ideas?

Comment: hmm seems as though it was caching results, but only in IE. I have added the line: WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache") to stop the method from caching the results and all seems to be working well now, although I hit the "Ajax client-side framework failed to load" error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm seems as though it was caching results, but only in IE.

I have added the line: WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache") to stop the method from caching the results and all seems to be working well now, although I hit the "Ajax client-side framework failed to load" error!